# How to run code in both foreground and background in React Native - Android?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, background, foreground

I'm doing an task for listening message (even in background) and show it on UI.

I have done in listening messages real time. But if the app is in background, it doesn't receive messages in that time.

I ask for any ideas, helps.

I searched `HeadlessJS`, `react-native-background-task` but not work for me.

Actually, i want to run this app even in Background and Foreground.

Thank you for advanced.

It's my code until now

**index.android.js**

```
//Import libraries
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text
} from 'react-native';
import SmsListener from 'react-native-android-sms-listener';

//Main component
export default class Main extends Component {
  state = {
    lastMessage: ''
  }

  //Receive messages
  listen = SmsListener.addListener(message => {
    this.setState({ lastMessage: message.body });
    console.log('message');
  })

  //render UI
  render() {
    return (
      <Text> Message is: {this.state.lastMessage} </Text>
    );
  }
}

//Register component
AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReadMessageApp', () => Main);
```

Comment: AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('SomeTaskName', () => require('SomeTaskName'));

Comment: Can u give more detail plz!

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android.html